# there is no suitable user-defined conversion from "sf::Image" to "const std::string"

Tags: image, c++17, sfml

There is a code but it gives an error in visual studio, everything seems to be correct
if you remove 2 lines replacing them with
`

- Image ava6;
- ava6.loadFromFile("images/ava6.png");

- Texture herotexture;
- herotexture.loadFromFile("images/ava6.png");
  `
  then there are no errors but does not see the file when starting
  Failed to load image "". Reason: Unable to open file
  if you specify the full path to the file, it doesn’t see it either

(using Image ava6;
ava6.loadFromFile("images/ava6.png") the compiler considers "images/ava6.png" to be a string)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FamcG.png)

```
`#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, 0);
    RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Test"); //увеличили для удобства размер окна

    Image ava6;
    ava6.loadFromFile("images/ava6.png");

    Texture herotexture;//создаем объект Texture (текстура)
    herotexture.loadFromFile(ava6);//загружаем картинку

    Sprite herosprite;//создаем объект Sprite(спрайт)
    herosprite.setTexture(herotexture);//передаём в него объект Texture (текстуры)
    herosprite.setPosition(50, 25);//задаем начальные координаты появления спрайта

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(herosprite);//выводим спрайт на экран
        window.display();
    }`

    return 0;
}`
```

I tried changing the names, the path to the file does not help

Comment: You are trying to pass an `Image` where a string (the file name) is expected.  What is `herotexture.loadFromFile(ava6);` supposed to mean, seeing as `ava6` is not in fact a file? If you want to create a texture from image, there's `Texture::loadFromImage`